ASP.NET Core UseSpaStaticFiles should return 404 for missing static files
I have an ASP.NET Core single page app with client-side routing. We have it set to return the index.html page for any unknown path, so that the SPA can startup and handle rendering the page correctly.
Our static assets (css, js, png) also return the index.html page, which causes us a lot of trouble with our caching. I want it to return a 404 for all static files.
Is it possible to have named files like (css, js, png) all return a 404 if not found, but all other routes default to return index.html?
Here is our code that returns static files and serves the SPA:
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
app.UseSpa(spa => { spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp/src"; });

I expect that requests to named files return a 404, and paths return the index.html.
- GET /fileDoesntExist.js    -> 404
- GET /fileDoesntExist.css   -> 404
- GET /fileDoesExist.css     -> 200 fileDoesExist.css
- GET /aPage                 -> 200 index.html
- GET /someOtherPage         -> 200 index.html

EDIT:
As requested by Jason, here is the contents of my Program.cs and Startup.cs files:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;
using Serilog.Formatting.Json;

namespace NS;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }


    private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseSerilog().ConfigureAppConfiguration((hbc, app) => {
            var loggerConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration().Enrich.FromLogContext();

            if (hbc.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment()) {
                Log.Logger = loggerConfiguration.WriteTo
                    .Console(
                        outputTemplate:
                        "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {User} {Event} - {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}").MinimumLevel
                    .Information().MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information).MinimumLevel
                    .Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning).CreateLogger();
            } else {
                var fmt = new JsonFormatter(renderMessage: true);
                Log.Logger = loggerConfiguration.WriteTo.Console(fmt)
                    .MinimumLevel.Information()
                    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
                    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure", LogEventLevel.Warning) // disables the Entity Framework Core initialized Info messages
                    .MinimumLevel.Override("System.Net.Http.HttpClient", LogEventLevel.Warning)

                    .CreateLogger();
            }
        }).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
    }
}


Startup.cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using AspNetCore.Proxy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Dapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using SendGrid.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Serilog;
using Unchase.Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Extensions.Extensions;

namespace NS;

public class Startup {
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly string LocalhostOrigins = "_localhostOrigins";
    private readonly string HostedOrigins = "_hostedOrigins";

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }


    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddHealthChecks().AddCheck<BasicHealthCheck>("BasicHealthCheck", tags: new[] { "basic" });

        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(config => { config.RootPath = "ClientApp/build"; });

        services.AddProxies();

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        services.AddControllers();

        DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
        app.UseSerilogRequestLogging(opts => {
            opts.EnrichDiagnosticContext = LogHelper.EnrichFromRequest;
            opts.GetLevel = LogHelper.ExcludeHealthChecks;
        });

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors(builder => builder
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
            .AllowCredentials()
        );


        if (!env.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpa(spa => { spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp/src"; });
        }

        if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseCors(LocalhostOrigins);
        } else {
            app.UseCors(LocalhostOrigins);
        }

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/healthz",
                new HealthCheckOptions { Predicate = check => check.Tags.Contains("basic") });
        });
    }
}


Hi Steve, please share your Program.cs, I need to check the middlewares. Please hide your sensitive information.

@JasonPan I added the two files to the question, thanks for looking into it!

Hi @Steve Sorry for replying you so late, please check this answer, hope it can help you.
